# View contents of SQL Azure database in storage emulator

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database

I've followed the official [.NET Web Application with SQL Azure tutorial](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-app-with-sql-azure/) on windowsazure.com and got it working locally and on Azure. When I run it locally, I can insert data into the database (into the ToDoItem-table) and it persists between sessions. The table is created using the Code First method.

Is there a way to view the database structure and contents of the tutorial database in the local SQL Azure database emulator?

Comment: Afaik, there is no sql database emulator. There is a storage emulator, for tables blobs and queues, but the tables are not sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not through the Storage Emulator no.

To view what Entity Framework has stored in your database you need to use **Sql Server Management Studio** (SSMS) to connect to your SQLEXPRESS database as it looks as though that is the database that tutorial uses. You can get a free express version of SSMS.

Comment: Thanks, I used SSMS and migrated my Code First code to Database First with SQLConnections. I guess it's time to abandon Code First.